# Structure pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm trying to print member variables of a structure by two different functions `save_struct_model_1` and `save_struct_model_2`. Both seem to work fine and print correct values. Which of these two is correct and preferred.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct model{
    char *name;
    int year;
};

void save_struct_model_1(struct model *s){
        printf("%s ", s->name);
        printf("%d \n",s->year);
}

void save_struct_model_2(struct model s){
        printf("%s ", s.name);
        printf("%d \n",s.year);
}

int main()
{

typedef struct model M;

M * honda = (M *) malloc (sizeof(M));
 honda->name="civic";
 honda->year=2000;

save_struct_model_1(honda);
save_struct_model_2(*honda);    

return 0;
}
```

Comment: The second one copies the temporary value from `*honda` and cannot alter the original struct.

Comment: Thanks @BlagovestBuyukliev,

Comment: `model_1` is almost always preferred. If you're only printing, use `void save_struct_model_1(const struct model *s);` Consider the general case where we have: `struct model { int x[1000000000]; };` Then, we'd push 4GB+ onto the stack. It would blow up the stack, not to mention the performance penalty on each call. That's why passing the struct pointer is done. In 35+ years of doing C, I've never had occasion to use model 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's mostly subjective. But I'd say the pointer version (using `save_struct_model_1()`) is better because it avoids copying the struct value.

It may not have any noticeable impact in your code -- but imagine if a struct having 100s of members and you'd want to print them all.

Comment: Got it, so given an option of pass by reference or by value, passing by reference is preferred.

Comment: @kris: C is a pass-by-value-only language. In the first variant, only the pointer is copied and in the second variant you copy the whole struct.

Comment: First of all, there's no "pass by reference" in C; everything is passed by value. Just what's passed (by value) is different. Mostly yes, passing a pointer is better because the struct copy can be potentially expensive. On the other hand, using `save_struct_model_2()` the `honda` at the caller can't be modified -- which may or may not what you want. As a general rule, I'd say use the pointer version *unless you have a good reason not to*.

Comment: oh yes, by 'reference' I meant copying the pointer and not the whole structure. I was confused with Java terminology: ) thanks for correcting.

Answer (score 0):

In `save_struct_model_1` function, the whole structure is passed to another function by address. It means only the address of the structure is passed to another function. The whole structure is not passed to another function with all members and their values. So, this structure can be accessed from called function by its address.

In `save_struct_model_2` function, the whole structure is passed to another function by value.It means the whole structure is passed to another function with all members and their values. So, this structure can be accessed from called function. This concept is very useful while writing very big programs in C.

Answer (score -1):

I think I'd do this:

```
int //to singnal errors in printf
save_struct_model_3(struct model const *s){
        //const to guarantee immutability 
        int r = 0;
        r |= 0>printf("%s ", s->name);
        r |= 0>printf("%d \n",s->year);
        return -r;
}
```

The difference between passing structs by a const pointer and passing structs by value is that the latter is slightly faster for very tiny structs (less indirection), whereas the former is faster for all other structs (no copying).

I once measured the overheads and it appears that on x86_64, passing by value starts losing when the size of the structs is greater or equal four int32_t's, which would make passing structs by pointers a good default strategy.

Here are my benchmarking results:

```
n_ints val/ns ptr/ns  
1   4.552   5.544
2   4.748   5.336
3   4.712   5.572
4   5.556   5.460 <<
5   6.180   4.436
6   5.252   5.424
7   5.620   4.100
8   4.316   4.164
9   5.612   4.220
10  6.656   4.656
11  6.148   4.472
12  6.708   4.708
13  6.192   5.200
14  8.560   4.652
15  7.392   4.620
16  8.512   4.728
17  8.244   5.488
18  10.108  5.360
19  8.540   4.740
20  10.028  5.468
```